# Sum of exponentials and variance of the exponents

Tags: variance, dataset, exponential-distribution

Let's assume we have two sets of non-negative real-valued numbers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ and $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$  ($N$ can be large) such that

1. $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}b_i=m$, (equal means)
2. $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}(a_i-m)^2=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}(b_i-m)^2=\epsilon$ (equal variances)

We happen to know that $|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}e^{-a_i}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}e^{-b_i}|<\eta$. Then, my question is:

Is there any mathematical relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\eta$?

Comment: Crossposted to math.SE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317102/  - please don't do this.   I'm not sure if I understand the question - are you actually asking for an upper bound for $|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}e^{-a_i}-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}e^{-b_i}|<\eta$  as a function of $\epsilon$? (Or possibly $\epsilon$ and $m$?)

Comment: Yes, that will do as well.

Comment: I think there must be a typographical error in this question.  It asks about the set of all possible $(\epsilon,\eta)$ subject to the assumptions about the $a_i$ and $b_i.$  But the answer is trivial, because no matter what $\epsilon$ might be, we can always take $a_i=b_i$ for all $i,$ entailing only that $\eta \gt 0.$ Conversely, no matter what $\eta$ might be, the same solution--$a_i=b_i$--shows that all mathematically possible values $\epsilon$ can occur.  That's no restriction at all.